# How to get IntelliJ IDEA 14 working with Scala on Android (SBT)

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-14

I'm using [android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) to make Android apps with Scala using SBT. This generally works great - however when trying to import the project into IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 the imported project looks rather empty and does not recognize my source files as being part of the project.

The documentation says:

> IntelliJ 14 now includes native support for importing projects from android-sdk-plugin. The process generally works well, however there are still several caveats:
>   The idea-sbt-plugin is still required to actually perform the build (no longer necessary as of IDEA 14.1)

Cloning and importing even the simplest [example project](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/tree/27a2a20ad49427b7a0389ddde1eafcbee4ff7853/sbt-test/android-sdk-plugin/auto-build) results in an empty IDE not showing any sources at all: [image: empty IDE]

I have installed both the Scala plug-in and the SBT plug-in (which I believe should no longer be required) as requested by the documentation.

What essential step am I missing?

Edit: I added the plug-in manually to `project/plugins.sbt`, then ran `gen-android` to get a `project/build.scala` containing `object Build extends android.AutoBuild`.

Comment: I don't have the Android SDK setup, so I can't verify but a few things: 1) Using an android-sdk-plugin scripted test won't work because the scripted plugin adds the plugin when running the test so IntelliJ won't find it 2) I'd recommend uninstalling the SBT plugin as it's been completely folded into the Scala plugin, and might get in the way

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I added the plug-in manually to `project/plugins.sbt`, then ran `gen-android` to get a project/build.scala containing `object Build extends android.AutoBuild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential step missing is the **Android plug-in** of IDEA. This might seem obvious but in contrast to plug-ins for other frameworks this one does not just provide extra goodies but is actually essential for anything Android.

Having the plug-in installed allows for selecting Android as a Project SDK (which not just selects an Android SDK but also a Java SDK to go with it).